# Rotate, Crop image using Guillotine plugin and Laravel 5 Intervention

Tags: php, image-processing, laravel-5, intervention

I work on image editor module, using [guillotine](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine) plugin.

I get parameters from ajax.

`{angle: 0,h: 600,scale: 6.7811,w: 800,x: 0,y: 485}`

In laravel I have this code

```
    $img = \Input::get('img');
    $data = \Input::get('data');

    $image = \Image::make($img)->rotate((int)$data['angle']);

    // crop image
    $image->crop((int)$data['w'], (int)$data['h'], (int)$data['x'], (int)$data['y']);
    $image->save('uploads/tmp/img.png');
```

The code is working , but the result is not the same as the user selected area. 
I guess I need to use 'scale' attribute too, but I don't know how.

For example : user selected area

[image]

Result

[image]

I appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the scale factor
then multiply it by the image width by using the [widen()](http://image.intervention.io/api/widen) function, it:

> Resizes the current image to new width, constraining aspect ratio

so the height will also get scale

```
    $img = \Input::get('img');
$data = \Input::get('data');

list($type, $img) = explode(';', $img);
list(, $img)      = explode(',', $img);
$img = base64_decode($img);

// save image
$img = file_put_contents('uploads/tmp/img.png', $img); 
$image = \Image::make('uploads/tmp/img.png')->rotate((float)$data['angle']);

//we get the image width then multiply it by the scale factor, it will also scale the height automatically
$image->widen((int)$image->width()*$data['scale']);


// crop image
$image->crop((int)$data['w'], (int)$data['h'], (int)$data['x'], (int)$data['y']);
$image->save('uploads/tmp/img.png');
```

Comment: Now , it's not even cropping .

Comment: This was correct solution. I had more bugs in my javascript so I thought this was not correct answer . Thank you! :)

Comment: @SomethingElse What is the return data of the `Input::get('img')`? I'm also facing the same problem.